# I don't have the primevue and tailwind style on my components

Tags: vue.js, tailwind-css, primevue

first of all I apologize for my slightly poor English. I have a problem that I can't solve, I installed Vue.js, and the primeVue library without forgetting tailwind. However, when I wanted to use a component like the button or a primevue checkbox, I didn't see any style displayed... and I don't know why.

HelloWorld.vue

```
<script setup>

import Button from 'primevue/button';
import { button } from '../styles/styles';


defineProps({
  msg: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
})

</script>

<template>
  <div class="greetings">
    <div class="card flex justify-center">
        <Button label="Submit" :pt="button.button"/>
    </div>
    <h1 class="green">{{ msg }}</h1>
    <h3>
      You’ve successfully created a project with
      <a href="https://vitejs.dev/" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Vite</a> +
      <a href="https://vuejs.org/" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Vue 3</a>.
    </h3>
  </div>
</template>
```

main.js

```
import './assets/main.css'

import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import PrimeVue from 'primevue/config'
import 'primeicons/primeicons.css'


const app = createApp(App);
app.use(PrimeVue, {
    unstyled: true
});

app.use(router)

app.mount('#app')
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "test-tom",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "primeicons": "^6.0.1",
    "primevue": "^3.44.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.6",
    "vue": "^3.3.10",
    "vue-router": "^4.2.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^4.5.1",
    "vite": "^5.0.5"
  }
}
```

main.css

```
@import './base.css';
@import 'tailwindcss/base';
@import 'tailwindcss/components';
@import 'tailwindcss/utilities';


@layer tailwind-base, primevue, tailwind-utilities;

/* Initial Values */
:root {
    --primary-50: 236 253 245;
    --primary-100: 209 250 229;
    --primary-200: 167 243 208;
    --primary-300: 110 231 183;
    --primary-400: 52 211 153;
    --primary-500: 16 185 129;
    --primary-600: 5 150 105;
    --primary-700: 4 120 87;
    --primary-800: 6 95 70;
    --primary-900: 4 78 56;
    --primary-950: 2 44 34;
    
    --surface-0: 255 255 255;
    --surface-50: 249 250 251;
    --surface-100: 243 244 246;
    --surface-200: 229 231 235;
    --surface-300: 209 213 219;
    --surface-400: 156 163 175;
    --surface-500: 107 114 128;
    --surface-600: 75 85 99;
    --surface-700: 55 65 81;
    --surface-800: 31 41 55;
    --surface-900: 17 24 39;
    --surface-950: 8 8 8;
}
```

styles.js

```
import * as button from './base/buttonStyle'
import * as checkbox from './base/checkboxStyle'

export {
    button,
    checkbox,
}
```

tailwind.config.js

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./index.html",
    "./src/**/*.{vue,js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./node_modules/primevue/**/*.{vue,js,ts,jsx,tsx}"  //primevue
],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        'primary-50': 'rgb(var(--primary-50))',
        'primary-100': 'rgb(var(--primary-100))',
        'primary-200': 'rgb(var(--primary-200))',
        'primary-300': 'rgb(var(--primary-300))',
        'primary-400': 'rgb(var(--primary-400))',
        'primary-500': 'rgb(var(--primary-500))',
        'primary-600': 'rgb(var(--primary-600))',
        'primary-700': 'rgb(var(--primary-700))',
        'primary-800': 'rgb(var(--primary-800))',
        'primary-900': 'rgb(var(--primary-900))',
        'primary-950': 'rgb(var(--primary-950))',
        'surface-0': 'rgb(var(--surface-0))',
        'surface-50': 'rgb(var(--surface-50))',
        'surface-100': 'rgb(var(--surface-100))',
        'surface-200': 'rgb(var(--surface-200))',
        'surface-300': 'rgb(var(--surface-300))',
        'surface-400': 'rgb(var(--surface-400))',
        'surface-500': 'rgb(var(--surface-500))',
        'surface-600': 'rgb(var(--surface-600))',
        'surface-700': 'rgb(var(--surface-700))',
        'surface-800': 'rgb(var(--surface-800))',
        'surface-900': 'rgb(var(--surface-900))',
        'surface-950': 'rgb(var(--surface-950))'
    }
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

buttonStyle.js

```
export const button = {
    root: ({ props, context }) => ({
        class: [
            'relative',

            // Alignments
            'items-center justify-center inline-flex text-center align-bottom',

            // Sizes & Spacing
            'text-sm',
            {
                'px-2.5 py-1.5 min-w-[2rem]': props.size === null && props.label !== null,
                'px-2 py-1': props.size === 'small',
                'px-3 py-2': props.size === 'large'
            },
            {
                'h-8 w-8 p-0': props.label == null
            },

            // Shapes
            { 'shadow-sm': !props.raised && !props.link && !props.text, 'shadow-lg': props.raised },
            { 'rounded-md': !props.rounded, 'rounded-full': props.rounded },

            // Link Button
            { 'text-primary-600 bg-transparent ring-transparent': props.link },

            // Plain Button
            { 'text-white bg-gray-500 ring-1 ring-gray-500': props.plain && !props.outlined && !props.text },
            // Plain Text Button
            { 'text-surface-500': props.plain && props.text },
            // Plain Outlined Button
            { 'text-surface-500 ring-1 ring-gray-500': props.plain && props.outlined },

            // Text Button
            { 'bg-transparent ring-transparent': props.text && !props.plain },

            // Outlined Button
            { 'bg-transparent': props.outlined && !props.plain },

            // --- Severity Buttons ---

            // Primary Button
            {
                'text-white dark:text-surface-900': !props.link && props.severity === null && !props.text && !props.outlined && !props.plain,
                'bg-primary-500 dark:bg-primary-400': !props.link && props.severity === null && !props.text && !props.outlined && !props.plain,
                'ring-1 ring-primary-500 dark:ring-primary-400': !props.link && props.severity === null && !props.text && !props.outlined && !props.plain
            },
            // Primary Text Button
            { 'text-primary-500 dark:text-primary-400': props.text && props.severity === null && !props.plain },
            // Primary Outlined Button
            { 'text-primary-500 ring-1 ring-primary-500 hover:bg-primary-300/20': props.outlined && props.severity === null && !props.plain },

            // Secondary Button
            {
                'text-white dark:text-surface-900': props.severity === 'secondary' && !props.text && !props.outlined && !props.plain,
                'bg-surface-500 dark:bg-surface-400': props.severity === 'secondary' && !props.text && !props.outlined && !props.plain,
                'ring-1 ring-surface-500 dark:ring-surface-400': props.severity === 'secondary' && !props.text && !props.outlined && !props.plain
            },
            // Secondary Text Button
            { 'text-surface-500 dark:text-surface-400': props.text && props.severity === 'secondary' && !props.plain },
            // Secondary Outlined Button
            { 'text-surface-500 ring-1 ring-surface-500 hover:bg-surface-300/20': props.outlined && props.severity === 'secondary' && !props.plain },

            // Success Button
            {
                'text-white dark:text-surface-900': props.severity === 'success' && !props.text && !props.outlined && !props.plain,
                'bg-green-500 dark:bg-green-400': props.severity === 'success' && !props.text && !props.outlined && !props.plain,
                'ring-1 ring-green-500 dark:ring-green-400': props.severity === 'success' && !props.text && !props.outlined && !props.plain
            },
            // Success Text Button
            { 'text-surface-500 dark:text-surface-400': props.text && props.severity === 'secondary' && !props.plain },
            // Success Outlined Button
            { 'text-green-500 ring-1 ring-green-500 hover:bg-green-300/20': props.outlined && props.severity === 'success' && !props.plain },

            // Info Button
            {
                'text-white dark:text-surface-900': props.severity === 'info' && !props.text && !props.outlined && !props.plain,
                'bg-blue-500 dark:bg-blue-400': props.severity === 'info' && !props.text && !props.outlined && !props.plain,
                'ring-1 ring-blue-500 dark:ring-blue-400': props.severity === 'info' && !props.text && !props.outlined && !props.plain
            },
            // Info Text Button
            { 'text-blue-500 dark:text-blue-400': props.text && props.severity === 'info' && !props.plain },
            // Info Outlined Button
            { 'text-blue-500 ring-1 ring-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-300/20 ': props.outlined && props.severity === 'info' && !props.plain },

            // Warning Button
            {
                'text-white dark:text-surface-900': props.severity === 'warning' && !props.text && !props.outlined && !props.plain,
                'bg-orange-500 dark:bg-orange-400': props.severity === 'warning' && !props.text && !props.outlined && !props.plain,
                'ring-1 ring-orange-500 dark:ring-orange-400': props.severity === 'warning' && !props.text && !props.outlined && !props.plain
            },
            // Warning Text Button
            { 'text-orange-500 dark:text-orange-400': props.text && props.severity === 'warning' && !props.plain },
            // Warning Outlined Button
            { 'text-orange-500 ring-1 ring-orange-500 hover:bg-orange-300/20': props.outlined && props.severity === 'warning' && !props.plain },

            // Help Button
            {
                'text-white dark:text-surface-900': props.severity === 'help' && !props.text && !props.outlined && !props.plain,
                'bg-purple-500 dark:bg-purple-400': props.severity === 'help' && !props.text && !props.outlined && !props.plain,
                'ring-1 ring-purple-500 dark:ring-purple-400': props.severity === 'help' && !props.text && !props.outlined && !props.plain
            },
            // Help Text Button
            { 'text-purple-500 dark:text-purple-400': props.text && props.severity === 'help' && !props.plain },
            // Help Outlined Button
            { 'text-purple-500 ring-1 ring-purple-500 hover:bg-purple-300/20': props.outlined && props.severity === 'help' && !props.plain },

            // Danger Button
            {
                'text-white dark:text-surface-900': props.severity === 'danger' && !props.text && !props.outlined && !props.plain,
                'bg-red-500 dark:bg-red-400': props.severity === 'danger' && !props.text && !props.outlined && !props.plain,
                'ring-1 ring-red-500 dark:ring-red-400': props.severity === 'danger' && !props.text && !props.outlined && !props.plain
            },
            // Danger Text Button
            { 'text-red-500 dark:text-red-400': props.text && props.severity === 'danger' && !props.plain },
            // Danger Outlined Button
            { 'text-red-500 ring-1 ring-red-500 hover:bg-red-300/20': props.outlined && props.severity === 'danger' && !props.plain },

            // --- Severity Button States ---
            'focus:outline-none focus:outline-offset-0 focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-current',
            { 'focus:ring-offset-2': !props.link && !props.plain && !props.outlined && !props.text },

            // Link
            { 'focus:ring-primary-500 dark:focus:ring-primary-400': props.link },

            // Plain
            { 'hover:bg-gray-600 hover:ring-gray-600': props.plain && !props.outlined && !props.text },
            // Text & Outlined Button
            { 'hover:bg-surface-300/20': props.plain && (props.text || props.outlined) },

            // Primary
            { 'hover:bg-primary-600 dark:hover:bg-primary-300 hover:ring-primary-600 dark:hover:ring-primary-300': !props.link && props.severity === null && !props.text && !props.outlined && !props.plain },
            { 'focus:ring-primary-500 dark:focus:ring-primary-400': props.severity === null },
            // Text & Outlined Button
            { 'hover:bg-primary-300/20': (props.text || props.outlined) && props.severity === null && !props.plain },

            // Secondary
            { 'hover:bg-surface-600 dark:hover:bg-surface-300 hover:ring-surface-600 dark:hover:ring-surface-300': props.severity === 'secondary' && !props.text && !props.outlined && !props.plain },
            { 'focus:ring-surface-500 dark:focus:ring-surface-400': props.severity === 'secondary' },
            // Text & Outlined Button
            { 'hover:bg-surface-300/20': (props.text || props.outlined) && props.severity === 'secondary' && !props.plain },

            // Success
            { 'hover:bg-green-600 dark:hover:bg-green-300 hover:ring-green-600 dark:hover:ring-green-300': props.severity === 'success' && !props.text && !props.outlined && !props.plain },
            { 'focus:ring-green-500 dark:focus:ring-green-400': props.severity === 'success' },
            // Text & Outlined Button
            { 'hover:bg-green-300/20': (props.text || props.outlined) && props.severity === 'success' && !props.plain },

            // Info
            { 'hover:bg-blue-600 dark:hover:bg-blue-300 hover:ring-blue-600 dark:hover:ring-blue-300': props.severity === 'info' && !props.text && !props.outlined && !props.plain },
            { 'focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:ring-blue-400': props.severity === 'info' },
            // Text & Outlined Button
            { 'hover:bg-blue-300/20': (props.text || props.outlined) && props.severity === 'info' && !props.plain },

            // Warning
            { 'hover:bg-orange-600 dark:hover:bg-orange-300 hover:ring-orange-600 dark:hover:ring-orange-300': props.severity === 'warning' && !props.text && !props.outlined && !props.plain },
            { 'focus:ring-orange-500 dark:focus:ring-orange-400': props.severity === 'warning' },
            // Text & Outlined Button
            { 'hover:bg-orange-300/20': (props.text || props.outlined) && props.severity === 'warning' && !props.plain },

            // Help
            { 'hover:bg-purple-600 dark:hover:bg-purple-300 hover:ring-purple-600 dark:hover:ring-purple-300': props.severity === 'help' && !props.text && !props.outlined && !props.plain },
            { 'focus:ring-purple-500 dark:focus:ring-purple-400': props.severity === 'help' },
            // Text & Outlined Button
            { 'hover:bg-purple-300/20': (props.text || props.outlined) && props.severity === 'help' && !props.plain },

            // Warning
            { 'hover:bg-red-600 dark:hover:bg-red-300 hover:ring-red-600 dark:hover:ring-red-300': props.severity === 'danger' && !props.text && !props.outlined && !props.plain },
            { 'focus:ring-red-500 dark:focus:ring-red-400': props.severity === 'danger' },
            // Text & Outlined Button
            { 'hover:bg-red-300/20': (props.text || props.outlined) && props.severity === 'danger' && !props.plain },

            // Disabled
            { 'opacity-60 pointer-events-none cursor-default': context.disabled },

            // Transitions
            'transition duration-200 ease-in-out',

            // Misc
            'cursor-pointer overflow-hidden select-none'
        ]
    }),
    label: ({ props }) => ({
        class: [
            'duration-200',
            'font-semibold',
            {
                'hover:underline': props.link
            },
            { 'flex-1': props.label !== null, 'invisible w-0': props.label == null }
        ]
    }),
    icon: ({ props }) => ({
        class: [
            'before:text-xs before:leading-none',
            'mx-0',
            {
                'mr-2': props.iconPos == 'left' && props.label != null,
                'ml-2 order-1': props.iconPos == 'right' && props.label != null,
                'mb-2': props.iconPos == 'top' && props.label != null,
                'mt-2': props.iconPos == 'bottom' && props.label != null
            }
        ]
    }),
    loadingicon: ({ props }) => ({
        class: [
            'h-3 w-3',
            'mx-0',
            {
                'mr-2': props.iconPos == 'left' && props.label != null,
                'ml-2 order-1': props.iconPos == 'right' && props.label != null,
                'mb-2': props.iconPos == 'top' && props.label != null,
                'mt-2': props.iconPos == 'bottom' && props.label != null
            }
        ]
    }),
    badge: ({ props }) => ({
        class: [{ 'ml-2 w-4 h-4 leading-none flex items-center justify-center': props.badge }]
    })
}
```

I don't know what to do...

Comment: I found it ! I forgot to use : 
npm install -D tailwindcss@latest postcss@latest autoprefixer@latest
npx tailwindcss init -p

Now it's ok ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it! I forgot to use:

```
npm install -D tailwindcss@latest postcss@latest autoprefixer@latest 
npx tailwindcss init -p
```

Now it's ok ;)